# I have to enter twice for my getchar() to work

Tags: c, fgets, getchar

I have trobule with getchar(). I have to enter twice for my code to work properly. I write my code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LEN 20

struct part {
    int number;
    char name[MAX_LEN + 1];
} part_1;
 
int main(void){
    int ch, th; 

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter operation code: ");
        while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF){
            switch (ch){

                case 'i': 
                printf("Enter part number: ");
                scanf("%d",&part_1.number);

                while ( (th = getchar()) != '\n'); /*I use this to remove newline character*/

                printf("Enter part name: ");
                fgets(part_1.name,MAX_LEN,stdin);
                break; 
                
                case 'q': exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running the compiler, I expect my result to be like this:

```
Enter operation code: i
Enter part number: 1
Enter part name: test
Enter operation code: i
```

However, I have to enter twice for the code to work properly:

```
Enter operation code: i
Enter part number: 1
Enter part name: test
-> /* This is where I have to press 'Enter' twice */
Enter operation code: i
```

Comment: NOTE: the function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: I have edited my code as you suggested and tried to run the code again but the problem has not been solved yet.

Comment: regarding: `while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n')`  The code needs to also check for EOF

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you help me figure out the problem with my code?

Comment: Please do not be modifying the original question.  Rather add a EDIT.  Otherwise the comments become meaningless, thereby just confusing future readers of the question

Comment: You almost certainly want an `fflush` after you print the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter a part name and press enter `fgets` will return and `break` out from the switch-statement and go back to the while-statement:  `while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF){`. You then need to press enter one more time to make the condition `false` so that it goes back to the `for`-statement in which it will print "Enter operation code: " again.

Basically you want to find a way to break out from *both* the switch-statement and while-statement when a part name has been read.

Now, I'm not sure exactly *you* want it to behave, but you could try to replace the while-statement with:

```
[...]
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter operation code: ");
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch != '\n') getchar();  // remove linebreak from stdin
        switch (ch){
[...]
```

with that the output will look like this:

```
Enter operation code: a
Enter operation code: b
Enter operation code: c
Enter operation code: i
Enter part number: 1234
Enter part name: hello
Enter operation code: d
Enter operation code: e
Enter operation code: f
Enter operation code:
Enter operation code:
Enter operation code: q
```

Comment: I imagine that ```scanf``` will leave a newline character behind, so I use ```while (th = getchar()) != '\n'``` to eat that newline character, so I will be able to use ```fgets``` to insert the info into ```part_1.name```.

Comment: I meant the while-statement after `printf("Enter operation code: ");`. Note that `fgets` does read the newline, so `part_1.name` will contain a newline character.

Comment: I do as you suggested and it works fine. However, if I change my old code like this:
```fgets(part_1.name,MAX_LEN,stdin);
getchar();``` 
and remove the -while statement after ```scanf("%d",&part_1.number)```, I will achieve the same result as your code. Can you explain me why?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because it was some time since I worked with reading from stdin in C, but I think that is because `scanf` can read and discard characters until it finds the type of character that is looking for, in this case a number. What do you see if you print the contents of `part_1.number` after that change?

Comment: If I follow your code, I did successfully print the contents of both ```part_1.number``` and ```part_1.name```. However, if I put the ```getchar``` after ```fgets```, print ```part_1.name``` returns nothing. However, I understand the problem now. ```fgets``` will eat the newline and ```getchar``` will wait for me to enter something. After that, it will read a character and leave the newline for the next -while loop. That's why I seemed to achieve the result as you got but in fact, it just "looks like that but not like that". Now I understand C more clearly. Really appreciate your help.